# Baking data into and csv and reading them back in numpy

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am baking some data into a csv file since it take a while to compute. The data is a list of tuples, short version here:

```
[(90, 5, '69.1'), (91, 5, '59.8'), (90, 6, '48.1'), (91, 6, '41.8')]
```

I'm doing it this way:

```
# Save results
import csv

with open('results/bake.csv','w') as out:
    csv_out=csv.writer(out)
    for row in data:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

but when I read it back in this way:

```
with open('results/bake.csv', 'Ur') as f:
    data = list(tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))


x, y, z = zip(*data)
z = map(float, z)
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]
grid_z = griddata((x, y), z, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
```

I am getting this error :

```
     grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[min(x):max(x):100j, min(y):max(y):100j]
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py", line 188, in __getitem__
  step = key.step 
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'step'
```

It must be something I'm doing wrong when writing and reading back the data since when I feed the data directly without caching in a csv file, it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` and `y` are lists of string, you need to convert them to list of floats:

```
x = map(float, x)
y = map(float, y)
```